# WPF Popup - not possible to use DynamicResource

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, popup, xceed

I am using the [DropDownButton](https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit/wiki/DropDownButton) from the [Xceed Wpf Toolkit](https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit).
In that popup I just want to display a manually-filled `ListView`.
A `ListViewItem` is just a vertical `StackPanel` with an `Image` and a `TextBlock`.

```
    <xceed:DropDownButton Grid.Column="4" x:Name="BurgerButton">
      <xceed:DropDownButton.Content>
        <Image Source="/Resources/BurgerMenu_128x128.png"/>
      </xceed:DropDownButton.Content>
      <xceed:DropDownButton.DropDownContent>
        <ListView>
          <ListViewItem cal:Message.Attach="[Event MouseUp] = [Action NewProject]">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
              <Image Source="/Resources/FileNew_32x32.png"/>
              <TextBlock Text="{DynamicResource ProjectSelectorView_NewProject}"/>
            </StackPanel>
          </ListViewItem>

          <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
              <Setter Property="DataContext" Value="{Binding DataContext, ElementName=BurgerButton}"/>
            </Style>
          </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        </ListView>
      </xceed:DropDownButton.DropDownContent>
    </xceed:DropDownButton>
```

I am using Caliburn.Micro to trigger an `Action` when the `MouseUp` event of the `ListViewItem` fires. This works fine. The problem ist the `<TextBlock Text="{DynamicResource ProjectSelectorView_NewProject}"/>` It is just empty, despite the resource being there. Everywhere else in the project the `DynamicResource` syntax works fine. It just doesn't work inside the `Popup`. I know that a Popup doesn't reside in the same VisualTree as the main application - so `DataContext` sharingis a bit harder.

This isn't about the `DataContext` though, it is about the `ResourceDictionary` defined in the `App.xaml`. my `App.xaml` looks like this:

```
<Application x:Class="Projectname"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CVBRecorder">
  <Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
      <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary>
          <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Localization/English.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Localization/German.xaml"/>
          </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary>
          <local:AppBootstrapper x:Key="bootstrapper" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
      </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
  </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Anyone know why the DynamicResource is not displayed inside a WPF popup?

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue. Please provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when asking a question.

Comment: Hi @mm8, I can reproduce this in a minimal project. The problem only exists when using the DropDownButton from Xceed. The normal WPF popup finds the resource just fine. I guess I'll open a Github issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this is a bug in the Xceed WPF Toolkit. I used version `3.2.0` which had the bug. Updating to `3.4.0` solved the problem.